# Eclipse auto-indent incorrectly indents file

Tags: java, eclipse, indentation, auto-indent

Something weird is happening to my Eclipse that I never remember happening before. Basically if I've got a long statement and split it onto two lines, then everything after that gets indented a tab further than it should be. Here's an example:

Correct indentation:

```
public static class Shape {

    enum Tetrominoes { NoShape, ZShape, SShape, LineShape, TShape, 
        SquareShape, LShape, MirroredLShape };

    private Tetrominoes pieceShape;
    private int coords[][];
    private int[][][] coordsTable;

    public Shape() {

        coords = new int[4][2];
        setShape(Tetrominoes.NoShape);
    }

    public void setShape(Tetrominoes shape) {

    }

}
```

What it looks like with Ctrl+A, Ctrl+I:

```
public static class Shape {

    enum Tetrominoes { NoShape, ZShape, SShape, LineShape, TShape, 
        SquareShape, LShape, MirroredLShape };

        private Tetrominoes pieceShape;
        private int coords[][];
        private int[][][] coordsTable;

        public Shape() {

            coords = new int[4][2];
            setShape(Tetrominoes.NoShape);
        }

        public void setShape(Tetrominoes shape) {

        }

}
```

Now if I keep that enum on one line and auto-indent it, then it works out just fine. I just got a new laptop and put a fresh copy of Eclipse on it and didn't change any settings, so this is how the default auto-indent works. But I remember on my old laptop if I would split a statement onto two lines then everything else after that would still be properly aligned?

(Also at the start of this post I put "Hey guys," but it looks like StackOverflow automatically removed it? I tried editing the question and reinserting it but it still got removed once posting. I tried putting "Hey," but that got removed too. Does SO not believe in greetings??)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to reproduce the issue.

It seems that the ending brace for the enum is confusing Eclipse. If you put that on a separate line the indentation starts working fine :

```
public static class Shape {

    enum Tetrominoes { NoShape, ZShape, SShape, LineShape, TShape, 
        SquareShape, LShape, MirroredLShape 
    };

    private Tetrominoes pieceShape;
    private int coords[][];
    private int[][][] coordsTable;

    public Shape() {

        coords = new int[4][2];
        setShape(Tetrominoes.NoShape);
    }

    public void setShape(Tetrominoes shape) {

    }

}
```

You can also attempt to format the code (Ctrl + Shift + F) followed by correcting indentation (Ctrl + A and  Ctrl + I ). When you format the code, you'll notice that Eclipse also puts the ending brace on the next line instead of alongside the Enum constant body.

Comment: But the thing is, I want the line to split so I can keep my code small enough to fit in half the screen. the line splitting isn't the issue, the fact all the indentation following the line split screws up is.

Comment: @ProgrammingMakesMeQQ, I have updated my answer above. If you do not wish to alter Line Splitting, try putting the ending brace of the enum on a new line like above.

Comment: Awesome we just discovered that at the same time lol. I can do that for now I guess, but here's the strange thing. If you're initializing an array on multiple lines (e.g. int[] array = { 1, 1, 1, \n 1, 1 etc.};) then you can have the ending brace on the same line as the end of your array initialization and the auto-indent works fine. So it's weird that for an enum you have to put the closing brace on a new line to get indentation to work fine but for an array you don't have to do that.